# Apache web server not running

Tags: release-loki

I have recently installed Xamp package and tried `./manager-linux-x64.run` in `/opt/lampp folder`. After clicking start all button **MySQL, ProFTPD** shows running status but apache web service displays stop status. I have tried port *80,8080,9000,8079,2222* ... but all in vain. On port 80 firefox shows up after typing command
`lsof -i @0.0.0.0:80`. I have closed the browser and tried again but can't find struggle fruitful. Please suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting it with `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` in terminal.

It should start servers and give you an information that it works.
If it'll start properly, check if you can use it properly.

As I understand you're using GUI for xampp - I had a problem with it too and in my case I just purged xampp and installed it with another .run file (Probably the previous version). :)

P.S.
To shutdown all the servers use `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop` command.